# How can I change this function in R so that it changes the data frame in x?

Tags: r

The code below is my attempt at a function to change the data table in x.
The data table x has columns named MutationStatus and disease. When I plug x as the data table and y as the string within the disease column manually, the function works, however plugging it as a function does not.

```
diseaseMutation <- function(x,y) {
  x$MutationStatus[x$disease != y] = "WT"
  x$disease[x$disease != y] = y
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to return the 'x'

```
diseaseMutation <- function(x,y) {
  x$MutationStatus[x$disease != y] = "WT"
   x$disease[x$disease != y] = y
   x
 }
```

Comment: That outputs it, but is it possible to store this whole resulting table into x itself? Like, once x is changed it becomes the result of this function?

Comment: @NickL. YOu can do `x <- diseaseMutation(x, 'yourstring')`

Comment: Thank you so much! Greatly helpful